# C# Winform TreeView BeforeSelect event firing twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the before select event on a tree view to trigger a "Save your changes" cycle.

Everything works fine but I recently added in some validation of a few fields and a need to be able to cancel the event. It appears the `e.Cancel = true` in the below code causes the BeforeSelect event to fire twice.

```
private void TvEmps_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {

  if (dgchanged) {
    DialogResult dialogResult = 
         MessageBox.Show("Save your changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes) {
      BtnSaveAll_Click(sender, e);

      if (!isvalid) {
        e.Cancel = true; // this causes the beforeselect event to fire twice                      
        return;
      }

    }

  }

}
```

I have tried the following but I am still getting double prompted:

````
        {            

            if (dialogShowing) return;

            if (dgchanged == true)
            {
                dialogShowing = true;
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Save your changes?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                dialogShowing = false;

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)                
                {   
                    BtnSaveAll_Click(sender, e);
                    e.Cancel = !isvalid;                   
                }               
            }           
        }```
````

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` takes the focus away, and then when the message box is closed, it gives the focus back to the TreeView, thus resulting in a BeforeSelect event firing again.  Don't put MessageBoxes in there.

Comment: Thanks but how do I do this without a message box? I need something to prompt the user?

Comment: The event won't fire more than once even if the control loses the focus and regains it again. Make sure you haven't subscribed to the event more than once by mistake. Also, taking this `BtnSaveAll_Click(sender, e)` into account, make sure that similar calls to the `BeforeSelect` event don't fire it redundantly.

Comment: There are actually two message box's tied to this. One shown in the above code and another one in the BtnSaveAll_Click. Removing both does indeed stop the event from firing twice but unfortunately this is not a solution. I need some type of interaction with the user.

Comment: @dr.null If the only code you have in the `BeforeSelect` event is `MessageBox.Show("Hey");` it will loop endlessly.

Comment: @LarsTech It will loop fore ever when? The event just fires once no matter what unless something else is firing it. So, the focus thing won't fire it again. Otherwise, give me something to reproduce it :). Thank you.

Comment: @dr.null I already did.

Comment: @dr.null Literally, all I have is `private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("Hey"); }` and when selecting a node, the "Hey" pops up over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the DialogBox is the cause of the BeforeSelect firing again, because it causes the TreeView control to regain the focus.

To work around the issue, try using a variable to determine if the dialog should be raised:

```
private bool dialogShowing = false;

private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (dialogShowing) return;

  dialogShowing = true;
  DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Confirm?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
  dialogShowing = false;
  if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
  {
    // call save
  } else
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried similar work around but I can't find a logical event to flip the dialogShowing = false;

Comment: @bikerider This should work.  Replace the "//call save" comment with `BtnSaveAll_Click(sender, e); e.Cancel = !isvalid;`

Comment: @bikerider "does not work" doesn't tell me anything.  I can't see your changed code from here.

Comment: @bikerider You mention in another comment "another MessageBox".  That could be causing issues with the "focus" part of the solution.

Comment: See edits above.. sorry about the formatting.

Comment: Yes, there is another messagebox but it is not the problem. I have temporarily removed that one and the problem still exists.

Comment: @bikerider Do this:  Comment out `\\BtnSaveAll_Click` and `e.Cancel = !isvalid;` lines and run it.  Obviously, it won't save anything, but it should run correctly.

Comment: @bikerider Also, the updated code you posted doesn't include the `} else {` part.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Adding back in the save call is not what is breaking it. It is the e.Cancel

Comment: @bikerider Well, my code is assuming your save routine is setting isvalid to true.  I don't know what's going on in the `BtnSaveAll_Click` method you have.

Comment: Exactly, the !isvalid flag is working as designed and cancelling the event correctly. Removing the save call and manually setting e.Cancel=true reproduces my results

Comment: @bikerider Maybe I'm misreading your intention.  `e.Cancel = true` means don't select the new node.

Comment: Correct, I want to return to the previous node because the validation failed.

Comment: @bikerider Sounds like `isvalid` is being set to false somewhere.  Use the debugger to check the value when it hits that line.

Comment: No, just for testing purposes I set the e.Cancel=true. It does cancel the event but I get the double prompts.

Comment: Seems to me this needs to go in a another event: dialogShowing = false; Because immediately setting it to false after showing the messagebox does nothing.

Comment: Figured it out as @dr.null mentioned it was another event that was causing the problems. In the NodeMouseClick event I had this: tvEmps.SelectedNode = e.Node;

Comment: Thanks for your patience!